# script in rc3.d not executing. correct place?

Tags: 18.04, bash, init.d

Maybe it needs to go somewhere else. I need to enable all the fans to %100. The script I use works if I run from a terminal but not on boot

```
ln -s /etc/init/setfan.sh /etc/rc3.d/S99setfan.sh

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Nov 23 19:59 S99setfan.sh -> /etc/init.d/setfan.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 326 Nov 23 19:55 /etc/init.d/setfan.sh

!/bin/bash
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=4

let NumGPU=12
let NumFAN=12

for (( n=0; n < NumGPU; n++))
do
/usr/bin/nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:$n]/GPUFanControlState=1"
done

for (( n=0; n < NumFAN; n++))
do
/usr/bin/nvidia-settings -a "[fan:$n]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=100"
done
```

Comment: This is not the problem, but scripts run through `/etc/rc?.d` are already `root`, so your use of `sudo` is unnecessary.

Comment: The execution context of `/etc/rc3.d/s99setfan.sh` differs from your desktop execution environment. Compare the results of `(echo "=== set ===";set;echo "===env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias)` in both.